# Preserving character set when importing .CSV file to MySQL

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I want to import an `.xlsx` file with ~60k rows to MySQL. Some columns contain Vietnamese characters. I managed to convert from `.xlsx` to `.csv` without messing up the character set. However I can't do the same when importing `.csv` to MySQL.

I used LOAD DATA INFILE. It looks something like this:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'c:/Projekt/Big Data/events.csv' 
INTO TABLE database.table 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
ENCLOSED BY '"' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
IGNORE 1 LINES;
```

(Source: http://blog.habrador.com/2013/01/how-to-import-large-csv-file-into-mysql.html)

This method imports the data fine but the character set of Vietnamese characters are totally messed up. I did change table's collation to `utf8_unicode_ci`.

I also test the traditional import method of MySQL with smaller datasets and it preserves the font perfectly. However I cannot use it since my file's size exceeds the limit of MySQL.

Really appreciate if someone could help me with this.

Comment: I think your question is misleading. "Fonts" denote the variable appearance of characters, e.g. in the font Arial, Times New Roman etc. Neither CSV nor MySQL are systems which have any notion of fonts. I think you're just talking about **handling encodings correctly** while importing data. For that: 1) what encoding is your CSV file in, 2) how are you importing it exactly?

Answer (score 2):

Try to explicit character set specify by import:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'c:/Projekt/Big Data/events.csv' 
INTO TABLE database.table 
CHARACTER SET utf8
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
ENCLOSED BY '"' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
IGNORE 1 LINES;
```

[See docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/load-data.html) for more details about loading from file.

Comment: If you have problems identifying which character set you mihght need to use, or indeed if you may be storing varied character sets in different rows, use `CHARACTER SET binary` to load the data without any conversion.

Comment: Thanks Injecto. I tried your method but MySQL showed an error.

Comment: Could you explain a little bit more about the use of CHARACTER SET binary Gavin?

Comment: @user3661376 I was mistaken: character set could be `utf8` instead of `utf8_unicode_ci`, of course. See edited answer.